# Using Newton's Divided Difference formula, prove that

Tags: numerical-methods

Using Newton's Divided Difference formula, prove that

$$f(x) = f(0) + x\,\Delta f(-1) +\frac{x(x+1)}{2!} \, \Delta^2f(-1) + \frac{(x+1)(x)(x-1)}{3!} \, \Delta^3f(-2)+ \cdots$$

where $\Delta$ is forward difference operator

Now i know that Newton's divided formula, but how do i prove above formula using that?

Thanks for helping me out

Comment: You should explain what $\Delta$ means in this context. I think I know what is meant, but it would still help.

Comment: I took a bit of a liberty in changing $\bigtriangleup$ to $\Delta$, but I also put a small space before it, so instead of $A\Delta B$ you see $A\,\Delta B$.  This is not a binary operator and should not have such a space on both sides.  If it referred to a symmetric difference, I'd put a space on both sides, just by writing \mathbin{\Delta}. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We will show the validity of OP's expression in two steps.

- At first we derive a representation of *Newton's divided difference formula* based upon operators which is convenient for further transformations.
- The second step is iteratively applying a representation of the identity operator in order to do proper rearrangements.

In the following we need three operators, the identity operator $I$ which leaves a function unchanged, the shift operator $E$, defined *pointwise* on a function by shifting the argument by $1$ and the difference operator $\Delta$, also defined pointwise. We get
 \begin{align*}
 If&=f\\
 Ef(x)&=f(x+1)\\
 \Delta f(x)&=f(x+1)-f(x)
 \end{align*}
 We also need a generalisation of the shift operator $E^a$ with $E^af(x)=f(x+a)$.  Since $\Delta f(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)=Ef(x)-If(x)=(E-I)f(x)$ we get the fundamental relationship
 \begin{align*}
 \Delta = E-I \qquad\text{resp.}\qquad E=I+\Delta\tag{1}\\
\end{align*}

> **First step:** Operator representation of *[Newton's Divided Difference formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_differences)*
>
> We look at the first few entries of $f(x_0),\ldots,f(x_n)$ and transform the formulas using operators. In order to do so, we make following
>
> *Assumption:* The interpolation points $x_0,\ldots,x_n$ are *equidistant* with $\Delta x_k=x_{k+1}-x_k=1$, with $0\leq k \leq n-1$.

$$ $$

> At first we analyse a case with small $n=4$
>   \begin{array}{ll}
> f(x_0)=f(x_0)=If(x_0)&\qquad \frac{f(x_1)-f(x_0)}{x_1-x_0}=Ef(x_0)-If(x_0)=(E-I)f(x_0)\\
> f(x_1)=f(x_0+1)=Ef(x_0)&\qquad \frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}=E^2f(x_0)-Ef(x_0)=E(E-I)f(x_0)\\
> f(x_2)=f(x_0+2)=E^2f(x_0)&\qquad \frac{f(x_3)-f(x_2)}{x_3-x_2}=E^3f(x_0)-E^2f(x_0)=E^2(E-I)f(x_0)\\
> f(x_3)=f(x_0+3)=E^3f(x_0)&\qquad \frac{f(x_4)-f(x_3)}{x_4-x_3}=E^4f(x_0)-E^3f(x_0)=E^3(E-I)f(x_0)\\
> f(x_4)=f(x_0+4)=E^4f(x_0)&\\
> \end{array}

$$ $$

> The next differences are
>   \begin{array}{l}
> \frac{\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}-\frac{f(x_1)-f(x_0)}{x_1-x_0}}{x_2-x_0}=\frac{1}{2}\left(E(E-I)-I(E-I)\right)f(x_0)=
> \frac{1}{2}(E-I)^2f(x_0)\\
> \frac{\frac{f(x_3)-f(x_2)}{x_3-x_2}-\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}}{x_3-x_1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(E^2(E-I)-E(E-I)\right)f(x_0)=
> \frac{1}{2}E(E-I)^2f(x_0)\\
> \frac{\frac{f(x_4)-f(x_3)}{x_4-x_3}-\frac{f(x_3)-f(x_2)}{x_3-x_2}}{x_4-x_2}=\frac{1}{2}\left(E^3(E-I)-E^2(E-I)\right)f(x_0)=
> \frac{1}{2}E^2(E-I)^2f(x_0)\\
> \end{array}
>   Note, the factor $\frac{1}{2}$ corresponds to $\frac{1}{x_{m+2}-x_m}$ and further steps with $\frac{1}{x_{m+k}-x_m}$ contribute a factor $\frac{1}{k}$ this way. The next differences are already much more conveniently described with operators
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{3}&\left(\frac{1}{2}E(E-I)^2f(x_0)-\frac{1}{2}(E-I)^2f(x_0)\right)=\frac{1}{3!}(E-I)^3f(x_0)\\
> \frac{1}{3}&\left(\frac{1}{2}E^2(E-I)^2f(x_0)-\frac{1}{2}E(E-I)^2f(x_0)\right)=\frac{1}{3!}E(E-I)^3f(x_0)\\
> \end{align*}
>   and the last difference is obviously
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{4!}(E-I)^4f(x_0)
> \end{align*}

We conclude the interpolation polynomial with equidistant points $x_0,\ldots,x_4$ and $\Delta x_k=1$ has the form

\begin{align*}
If(x_0)&+x(E-I)f(x_0)+\frac{1}{2}x(x-1)(E-I)^2f(x_0)\\
&\qquad+\frac{1}{3!}x(x-1)(x-2)(E-I)^3f(x_0)\\
&\qquad+\frac{1}{4!}x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(E-I)^4f(x_0)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{4}\binom{x}{k}(E-I)^kf(x_0)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{4}\binom{x}{k}\Delta^kf(x_0)\tag{2}
\end{align*}
Note, the last step (2) uses the relation (1) and  binomial coefficients as convenient notation.

> Since (2) is obviously related to the *[binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* we change the point of view and consider the *formal operator series*
>
> \begin{align*}
> E^x=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{x}{k}\Delta^k\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

Note, that (3) is a purely formal operator equation. There is no occurrence of a function $f$ and there is also a *shift of the meaning* of $x$, which is no longer treated as *variable* but instead as *operator*. The meaning of the *operator $x$* when applied to a function $f$ is simply *multiplication with $x$*.

> The equation (3) is the representation of Newton's interpolation polynomials based upon Newton's divided difference formula. We obtain with $x_0=0$
>   \begin{align*}
> f(x)&=E^xf(0)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{x}{k}\Delta^kf(0)\tag{4}\\
> &=f(0)+\binom{x}{1}\Delta f(0)+\frac{1}{2!}\binom{x}{2}\Delta ^2f(0)+\frac{1}{3!}\binom{x}{3}\Delta ^3f(0)+\cdots
> \end{align*}

$$ $$

> **Second step:** Rearrangement of the operator representation
>
> Since we have derived an operator representation, we will now *rearrange* it without changing it by applying the Identity operator $I$ in a specific manner.

The following is valid
\begin{align*}
E^{-1}(I+\Delta)=I
\end{align*}
since
\begin{align*}
E^{-1}(I+\Delta)f(x)&=E^{-1}(If(x)+\Delta f(x))\\
&=E^{-1}f(x)+E^{-1}(f(x+1)-f(x))\\
&=f(x-1)+f(x)-f(x-1)\\
&=f(x)
\end{align*}
Note, that the difference operator $\Delta$ and the shift operator $E^a$ commute, since
\begin{align*}
\Delta E^a f(x)&=\Delta f(x+a)\\
&=f(x+a+1)-f(x+a)\\
&= E^a f(x+1)- E^a f(x)\\
&=E^a \left(f(x+1) - f(x)\right)\\
&= E^a \Delta f(x)\\
\end{align*}

> We are ready for the rearrangement. We leave the first member of the series in (4) unchanged and apply the identity operator $I=E^{-1}(I+\Delta)$ to the other part.
>   \begin{align*}
> f(x)&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{x}{k}\Delta^kf(0)\\
> &=f(0)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\binom{x}{k}\Delta^kIf(0)\\
> &=f(0)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\binom{x}{k}\Delta^kE^{-1}(I+\Delta)f(0)\tag{5}\\
> &=f(0)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\binom{x}{k}\left(\Delta^k+\Delta^{k+1}\right)E^{-1}f(0)\tag{6}\\
> &=f(0)+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{x}{k+1}\Delta^{k+1}E^{-1}f(0)
> +\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\binom{x}{k}\Delta^{k+1}E^{-1}f(0)\tag{7}\\
> &=f(0)+\binom{x}{1}\Delta E^{-1}f(0)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\binom{x+1}{k+1}\Delta^{k+1}E^{-1}f(0)\tag{8}\\
> &=f(0)+\binom{x}{1}\Delta E^{-1}f(0)+\binom{x+1}{2}\Delta^2 E^{-1}f(0)\\
> &\qquad\qquad+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\binom{x+1}{k+1}\Delta^{k+1}E^{-1}f(0)\tag{9}\\
> &=f(0)+x\Delta f(-1)+\frac{1}{2}(x+1)x\Delta^2 f(-1)\\
> &\qquad\qquad+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\binom{x+1}{k+1}\Delta^{k+1}E^{-1}f(0)\tag{10}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (5) we use the relation $I=E^{-1}(I+\Delta)$
- In (6) we use the commutativity of the operators $E^a$ and $\Delta$
- In (7) we shift the index in the first sum
- In (8) we extract the summand with $k=0$ and use the relationship $\binom{n}{k-1}+\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k}$
- In (9) we extract the summand with $k=1$
- In (10) we apply the shift operator to $E^{-1}$ to $f(0)$

> Observe, that we could derive in (10) the first three summands of OPs expression. Now we apply *again* the identity operator to the series starting with $k=2$.
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}&\binom{x+1}{k+1}\Delta^{k+1}E^{-1}(I+\Delta)E^{-1}f(0)\\
> &=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\binom{x+1}{k+1}\left(\Delta^{k+1}+\Delta^{k+2}\right)E^{-2}f(0)\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\binom{x+1}{k+2}\Delta^{k+2}E^{-2}f(0)+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\binom{x+1}{k+1}\Delta^{k+2}E^{-2}f(0)\\
> &=\binom{x+1}{3}\Delta^{3}E^{-2}f(0)+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\binom{x+2}{k+2}\Delta^{k+2}E^{-2}f(0)\\
> &=\binom{x+1}{3}\Delta^{3}E^{-2}f(0)+\binom{x+2}{4}\Delta^{4}E^{-2}f(0)+\sum_{k=3}^{\infty}\binom{x+2}{k+2}\Delta^{k+2}E^{-2}f(0)\\
> &=\frac{1}{3!}(x+1)x(x-1)\Delta^{3}f(-2)+\frac{1}{4!}(x+2)(x+1)x(x-1)\Delta^{4}f(-2)\\
> &\qquad+\sum_{k=3}^{\infty}\binom{x+2}{k+2}\Delta^{k+2}E^{-2}f(0)\tag{11}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> Collecting (10) and (11) we obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> f(x)&=f(0)+x\Delta f(-1)+\frac{1}{2}(x+1)x\Delta^2 f(-1)\\
> &\qquad+\frac{1}{3!}(x+1)x(x-1)\Delta^{3}f(-2)+\frac{1}{4!}(x+2)(x+1)x(x-1)\Delta^{4}f(-2)\\
> &\qquad+\sum_{k=3}^{\infty}\binom{x+2}{k+2}\Delta^{k+2}E^{-2}f(0)\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\Box
> \end{align*}
>   and OP's claim follows by iteratively applying this method.

**Note:** A similar derivation of step 2 called *Interpolation by the Gauss series* is presented in chapter 7, paragraph 127 in C. Jordans classic *[Calculus of finite differences](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0828400334)*.

Comment: @TaylorTed: Thanks for accepting my answer and granting the bounty! :-) Best regards,